# Why only the first word from the input sentense is scanned and stored while using %s?

Tags: c, input

I'm trying to display the users answer  for input `answer2` but it's only displaying the first word of the complete input sentence.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
    char answer[20];
    char answer1[20];
    char answer2[100000];
    printf("What is your first name \n");
    scanf(" %s",answer);
    printf("What is your favorite color \n");
    scanf(" %s",answer1);
    printf("What is your quest \n");
    scanf(" %s",answer2);
    printf("Your name is %s,Your favorite color is %s,and your quest is s %s",answer,answer1,answer2);
    return 0;
}
```

[Screenshot of Program running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbmC6.png)

Comment: I suggest you use a debugger to step through your code to see what it is doing.

Comment: `scanf` stops reading characters once a white-space it found. Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: Because `scanf()` stops reading when it encounters a space. To read strings with space, use `fgets()`.

Comment: The `scanf` format `"%s"` reads ***space delimited*** words.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help harris

Comment: And don't post screenshots of text!

Comment: @Olaf and which one is missing?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Not all information in the question.

Comment: whats the plceholder for fgets

Comment: What do you mean with "placeholder"? That's noting the standard even mentions. Re your question: Why don't you check the results of `scanf`? Those would easily show the problem. Learn using a debugger.

Comment: @Olaf In general, that's a very good suggestion, but in this case, how checking the return value helps?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Detecting the fault before the invoking UB by accessing variables with indeterminate value?

Comment: @Olaf yes, in case of matching failure. but here, isn't the case is _not_ with unassigned variable, rather space delimited input? the variable will be assigned anyway, with excess input remaining in the buffer. How that can invoke UB or, checking the return value can indicate the issue _here_, firsthand?

Comment: @Olaf where is the UB? as far as I can see those strings are filled with a value: `will` , `green` and `to`

Comment: @AlterMann: I don't see proof in the question. Maybe the image contains more info, but ... see above.

Comment: @Olaf: Then you cannot see an UB either

Comment: @AlterMann: What if the `scanf`s fail? The automatic variables are not initialised, thus indeterminate. The final `printf` reads them - UB.

Comment: @Olaf, **7.19.6.2 The fscanf function** _If this object does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined._, but in this case the object is an array of chars and there is no conversion, OP's code can not fail (unless he types something larger than the buffer but that's not the point), IMO a debugger doesn't help here.

Comment: @AlterMann: Well, it very well does, as it can show the result of `scanf`. But you are right (and that was actually what I recommended already), the result should be check by the program code - as for all functions which can return an error and are vital for program execution.

Comment: Note that if you claim your first name is 'William Henry John', the code won't wait around for any more data to be entered.

Answer (score 1):

`%s` with `scanf()` stops scanning upon encountering a whitespace. So, you cannot use that to scan multiple *words*.

Quoting the standard, for `%s` conversion specifier, with `scanf()`

> `s` Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters.

So, it will scan until it founds a whitespace in the input. An input with multiple words (separated by whitespace) will not be completely scanned, only the *first word* will be scanned and stored.

Instead, a better approach will be using [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to to scan the input containing whitespaces, then strip off the trailing newline and tokenize (if required).

Comment: That's the prototype of a "debugging help" question (see my comment above)!

Comment: @Olaf Sorry I did not get your point.

Comment: Which one? I boldfaced the part from the CV in my comment to the OP.

Comment: @Olaf if you are pointing out about the question title, I agree it can be better, no doubt. However, the question body, as it is currently written (may not be perfect but) should be sufficient to understand and reproduce the issue.

Comment: You know the rules as I do. The image - worse a link to an image - is definitively wrong. And without that image, the question **is** without context. "... must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce **it in the question itself**."

Comment: @Olaf Did I miss something obvious in the question? If I'm not very wrong, _"....must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself"_ is present. The screenshot is _additional_ in this case.

Comment: "%s with scanf() stops scanning upon encountering a whitespace." misses that it does _not_ stop on leading spaces.  Instead it consumes (and not save) them until non-whitespace is encountered.